# Root Page - undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to insert an avatar image in my _header in the navigation.

When i try i receive this error.

I receive this error.

```
undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass
```

It is relation to this code on my _header view.

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:large) %>
```

How do i get the avatar to show?

Comment: It looks like your @user is nil.

Comment: @MuhamadAkbarBinWidayat Yeah thats what i thought. I know how to make it not nill in a crud view. But in the header i dont know how?

Comment: I see. Are you using devise for you apps? you can call current_user.avatar.url(:large)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your problem, this is the way how you can fix it:

controller/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user #make this method available in views

  def current_user
     # Use find_by_id to get nil instead of an error if user doesn't exist
     # you can change the session param based on your params
    @current_user ||= session[:current_user_id] && User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
  end
end
```

In View, you just call:

```
<%= current_user.avatar.url(:large) %>
```

If you use devise for login, you can call `<%= current_user.avatar.url(:large) %>` without make helper method in you application_controller.rb

I hope it can help you

Answer (score 1):

Your `@user` variable is nil, just wrap this code with conditions:

```
<% if @user.present? %>
  <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
<% end %>
```